# I can't import Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make an project with flask, but somehow, even if i installed it, i just cannot use flask!

i've tried to change the `from Flask import Flask, render_template, request` command by just `import Flask`, but nothing happen, could anyone help, please? Here is the code, if necessary:

```
import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
from flask import Flask
# 1st lowercase
```

Answer (score 1):

The import is `from flask import Flask`.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you used the same Python version to install flask as you did to run your app? I once installed flask for Python 2.6, but executed the script in Python 3, which also led to the fact that the flask could not be imported. Be sure that the versions are correct.

```
sudo pip install Flask

sudo pip3 install Flask
```